# Changing WiFi settings separately

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, dns

I'm using 2 WiFi networks with my MacBook Air. I need to switch between them sometimes. The problem is one needs completely different settings from the other, and it looks like I can only make settings for the particular WiFi network I am connected to at that moment.

Is there a way to set them separaely for specified network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different environments for your network (System preferences --> Network) and apply different settings to these environments.

[image: Create your environments]

If you now switch your WiFi you can also easily change the environment (unfortunately it is not possible to do this automatically - at least not with standard tools), by clicking onto the Apple logo in the menu bar.

[image]

(Sorry my OS X installation is in german language)